# Serving uploaded static files using grizzly embedded server

Tags: grizzly

I have developed a RESTful application using Jersey and grizzly embedded server. The multipart file upload is working but I don't know how to serve the uploaded static files when the client requests them.

My question may sound a bit general but I think my problem is also quite general. I can provide the details of my project if they are necessary but I am looking for a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample how you can add static and dynamic request processing:

```java
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(TestResource.class);
URI jerseyAppUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0/api")
        .port(8080).build();

// Jersey app at http://localhost:8080/api/...
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        jerseyAppUri, rc, false);

// Static content handler at http://localhost:8080/static/...
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
        new StaticHttpHandler("/home/user1/myapp/www/"), "/static");

// Dynamic content handler at http://localhost:8080/dynamic
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
    new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void service(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                response.getWriter().write("Hello World!");
            }
    }, "/dynamic");

httpServer.start();
```